# Can't rezise Ubuntu partition from live usb

Tags: partitioning

I have 300 GB approx that is unallocated so I tried to put that space on my Ubuntu partition that only has 90 GB approx. When I boot **GParted** from the live usb, it doesn't let me add that space. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't move "space" you can move partitions.

Run `sudo swapoff -a` in terminal, and you will be able to move and resize partitions.